# Telegram-bot api sendDocument error when i use RestTemplate in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, telegram, telegram-bot

I use Spring Boot 3.1, Telegram Bots Spring Boot Starter 6.7.0 and WebHook bot

I need to use class RestTemplate for call method /sendDocument in telegram API. I have read documentation telegram https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument and https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files, in my situation i need to send new binary pdf file.

I use next code:

```
public void sendNewPdfReport(Long chatId) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    File file = null;
    try {
        file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:reports/report.pdf");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    InputFile inputFile = new InputFile(file);

    body.add("chat_id", chatId);
    body.add("document", inputFile);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    restTemplate.postForEntity("https://api.telegram.org/bot<myToken>/sendDocument", requestEntity, String.class);
}
```

When i call this code i get an error:

API Telegram: 400 Bad Request: "{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Unsupported URL protocol"}"

2023-07-23 18:22:58,936 ERROR [http-nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getChatId()" because the return value of "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update.getMessage()" is null] with root cause

I don't understand what the problem is. I fill in the fields as indicated in the documentation.

I rewrote the code without using RestTemplate:

```
public void sendNewPdfReport2Work(Long chatId) {
    String uri = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<myToken>/sendDocument";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
    InputFile inputFile = new InputFile(new File("report.pdf"));

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addTextBody("chat_id", chatId.toString());
    builder.addBinaryBody(inputFile.getMediaName(), inputFile.getNewMediaFile(),
    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, inputFile.getMediaName());
    builder.addTextBody("document", inputFile.getAttachName());
    org.apache.http.HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();

    httppost.setEntity(multipart);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        httpClient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

AND IT IS WORK! BUT ... I need the code to work when using RestTemplate. I conclude that the problem is in the use of RestTemplate.

Help plz, How do I correctly use and configure RestTemplate to send binary files in /sendDocument telegram API

ok, I try with WebClient:

```
public void sendNewPdfReportWebClient(Long chatId) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(tgBotConfig.getTelegramApiUrl() + tgBotConfig.getBotToken());

    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    builder.part("chat_id", chatId);
    try {
        builder.part("document", new InputFile(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:reports/report.pdf")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    webClient.post()
            .uri(String.join("/sendDocument"))
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
            .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(HttpStatus.class).thenReturn(response.statusCode());
                } else {
                    throw new ServiceException("Error uploading file");
                }
            })
            .block();
}
```

I have the next error:

Error uploading file
2023-07-24 23:33:55,572 ERROR [http-nio-8088-exec-5] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getText()" because "message" is null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getText()" because "message" is null

[Telegram API /sendDocument from Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cgWe.png)

Log with debug:

```
New debugLog: 2023-07-25 17:57:11,141 INFO  [http-nio-8088-exec-1] r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
2023-07-25 17:57:11,142 INFO  [http-nio-8088-exec-1] r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: | request(unbounded)
2023-07-25 17:57:11,155 DEBUG [http-nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.c.l.LogFormatUtils: [1eebab11] HTTP POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<myToken>/sendDocument
2023-07-25 17:57:11,542 DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.l.LogFormatUtils: [1eebab11] [63f404bc-1] Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
2023-07-25 17:57:11,550 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-2] r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: | onNext({"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: Unsupported URL protocol"})
2023-07-25 17:57:11,551 INFO  [reactor-http-nio-2] r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: | onComplete()
```

[Headers in rest client Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isyh0.png)

In result r&d working code:

```
public void sendNewFileReport(Long chatId, String firstName, String reportPath) {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(tgBotConfig.getTelegramApiUrl() + tgBotConfig.getBotToken());
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = ResourceUtils.getFile(reportPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("chat_id", chatId);
        body.add("document", new FileSystemResource(file));

        webClient.post()
                .uri("/sendDocument")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(body))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .subscribe(
                        data -> log.info("Data: {}", data),
                        error -> log.error("Error: ", error),
                        () -> log.info("{},  has been sent successfully", firstName)
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ResetTemplate` with `spring boot 3.x`. `WebClient`
is the recommended for spring boot 3.

Comment: ok, I try with WebClient - in start post. I have the next error:

Error uploading file 2023-07-24 23:33:55,572 ERROR [http-nio-8088-exec-5] o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getText()" because "message" is null] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message.getText()" because "message" is null

Answer (score 0):

try with `LinkedMultiValueMap` like this.

```java
public void sendNewPdfReportWebClient(Long chatId) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(tgBotConfig.getTelegramApiUrl() + tgBotConfig.getBotToken());

    //** Create a MultiValueMap to hold the parts of the multipart form data
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    // Set the "Content-Type" header to "application/pdf"
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    parts.add("chat_id", chatId);
    try {
        parts.add("document", new InputFile(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:reports/report.pdf")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    webClient.post()
            .uri(String.join("/sendDocument"))
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers)) // Set the headers
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(parts))
            .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(HttpStatus.class).thenReturn(response.statusCode());
                } else {
                    throw new ServiceException("Error uploading file");
                }
            })
            .block();
}
```

Comment: i used this code, I get an error: Error uploading file. The file is still not being sent to the telegram API. In status code from server i get 404 NOT_FOUND

Comment: fix: In status code from server i get 400 BAD_REQUEST

Comment: please check your request with postman 1st after that inspect the webclient by enabling debug `logging.level.org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client=DEBUG`. then you can have a basic idea about the error. check  how the data has been blinded with the request from the log. if you cannot find the error please provide a screenshot that you took from the postman after testing the API by the postman.

Comment: add screen (1st post) from rest client Insomnia and enabled debug: 2023-07-25 17:40:09,990 DEBUG [http-nio-8088-exec-1] o.s.c.l.LogFormatUtils: [69e390b] HTTP POST https://api.telegram.org/bot<mytoken>/sendDocument
2023-07-25 17:40:10,367 DEBUG [reactor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.l.LogFormatUtils: [69e390b] [a0a136af-1] Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
2023-07-25 17:40:10,372 ERROR [http-nio-8088-exec-1] r.e.t.s.OnBoardingBot: Error uploading file

Comment: add new log in 1st post with debug

Comment: I think your code is correct but the headers are not set as they want. when you send by using the Postamn or any tool it normally add the headers regarding the file type.  but when we use webclient we have to add those headers manually. can you put the `Request headers' screenshot`. check this https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files API

Comment: I have updated the answer with new headers for PDF . please check it

Comment: I checked code with headers for PDF - The error has not changed. In 1st post added screen with headers from rest client